# Python 3: largest number in txt file

Tags: python-3.x, max

Thats my code:

```
def get_latest(file_name):
    max = 0
    with open(file_name) as file:
        for line in file.readlines():            
            num = int(line.split("\t")[2])
            if (max < num):
                max = num
            line=line.split("\t")
            #y=max
            if str(max) in line:
                print(line)

get_latest('game_stat.txt')
```

That's output:

```
['Minecraft', '23', '2009', 'Survival game', 'Microsoft\n']
['Terraria', '12', '2011', 'Action-adventure', 'Re-Logic\n']
['Diablo III', '12', '2012', 'RPG', 'Blizzard Entertainment\n']
```

What should I do to print only line with newest released date?

Txt file looks like this:

```
Minecraft   23  2009    Survival game   Microsoft
World of Warcraft   14  2004    RPG Blizzard Entertainment
Terraria    12  2011    Action-adventure    Re-Logic
Diablo III  12  2012    RPG Blizzard Entertainment
Half-Life 2 12  2004    First-person shooter    Valve Corporation
Counter-Strike  12.5    1999    First-person shooter    Valve Corporation
The Sims    11.24   2000    Simulation  Electronic Arts
StarCraft   11  1998    Real-time strategy  Blizzard Entertainment
Garry's Mod 10  2006    Sandbox Facepunch Studios
....etc
```

I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print(max(file, key=lambda line:int(line.split("\t")[2])).split.("\t"))`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Can You explain me how does it work? or give me a clue what should I read about? Thanks

Comment: Follow @PatrickHaugh 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `max` over all of your rows, with a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) that compares the years as integers.  Below, I use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to parse the structure of the file for me.

```
import csv

def get_latest(file_name):
    with open(file_name, newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, dialect='excel-tab')
        return max(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[2]))

print(get_latest('game_stat.txt'))
```

The entry with the largest year will be the most recently released.  (Assuming you don't have data for games coming out in the future.)

Comment: I have to do this without importing any modules like csv. Steven's Rumbalski answer was correct, but I just don't understand why it works. Can You explain it to me without importing anything? Thank You

Comment: Basically, we both use `max` to iterate over the file, keeping the maximum row (according to a key value).  `max` will iterate over the entire file, and will return a single value: the line that has the largest key value.  In contrast, your program prints every time the current line is the latest so far, which may be true multiple time instead of just once.